# ActionBar isn't displaying in API 16

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm a beginner, I have made an app which contains navigation drawer along with the action bar in mainactivity.It worked perfectly on API 23 but in API 16, action bar isn't showing up.I searched many links on "actionbar not displaying" but they were having problems below API 11/8.After API 11, I think AppCompat should work (which I have used)
Here are images

[image: On API 16]

[image: On API 23]

Here is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.portus.yehchina">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` why ? Use Toolbar

Comment: What code should I remove/add for properly implementing toolbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first , According to your requirement please remove this line from **manifest**

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

My Suggestion , Use **Toolbar instead of ActionBar** .

Comment: Removed that line, still the same case.And I don't know how to implement toolbar.That code might have auto-generated while using Navigation Drawer template.

Comment: okay , What is `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`

Comment: At first it was pre-written without parent attribute, then I tried adding parent as 
error: "AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.portus.yehchina/com.portus.yehchina.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
" 
was poping

Comment: @KamalVidhani at first go through http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example

Comment: I referred that.Thank you.I added the xml coded of toolbar widget that was missing.Now the problem is how to bring navigation drawer toggle icon and button on toolbar?

Comment: That's the another question .

Comment: I am extremely sorry . Just logout from #SO . Using Mobile . You ask new question .Hope anyone will helps you .