# Action Bar isn't displaying in API16

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to use a navigation drawer in my Main activity.
when i run it in API 23 Emulator , everything looks fine.
But when I run it in API 16 Emulator, my action bar goes away!

Here is my manifest file :

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is my styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/line1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/line1_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/isbc</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Here is my v21/styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/line1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/line1_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/isbc</item>
</style>
```

And this is my Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    changeTypeface(navigationView);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


private void applyFontToItem(MenuItem item, Typeface font) {
    SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(item.getTitle());
    mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font, 16), 0 ,
            mNewTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    item.setTitle(mNewTitle);
}


private void changeTypeface(NavigationView navigationView) {
    FontTypeface fontTypeface = new FontTypeface(this);
    Typeface typeface = fontTypeface.getTypefaceAndroid();

    MenuItem item;

    item = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_camera);
    item.setTitle("لیست ایستگاه ها");
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_stations);
    applyFontToItem(item, typeface);

    item = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_gallery);
    item.setTitle("نقشه");
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_map);
    applyFontToItem(item, typeface);

    item = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_slideshow);
    item.setTitle("درباره ما");
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_us);
    applyFontToItem(item, typeface);
}

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();        }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Here is my app_bar_main :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

When I run this code in emulator API 21, everything looks fine.
But when I run it in API 16, i get this error:
"This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not `request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR` and set `windowActionBar` to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead."

I guess it's telling me not to use actionbar, but how can i actually display my navigation drawer if i set windowActionBar to false?

[i've tried this topic but it didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453383/actionbar-isnt-displaying-in-api-16)

Comment: your activity theme should be AppTheme.NoActionBar instead of AppTheme

Comment: @RaviTeja but how can i display my navigation drawer if i set activity theme to NoActionBar?

Comment: it disables the toolbar that is already present in AppCompatActivity and your toolbar is added as an action bar.So you don't get the error and navigation drawer will be attached to your toolbar.

Comment: @RaviTeja it fixed navigation drawer problem, but now there is no ActionBar, how can i disbplay my ActionBar?

Comment: You can simply create a new project with `Navigation Drawer` template in Android Studio and check it with your project. Templates work in all versions after `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi Actually this is a Android studio Navigation Drawer template... My problem is that i can't Display actionBar in API16 When i create a Navigation Drawer Activity.

Comment: please post your layout file

Comment: @RaviTeja i did , check it out.

Comment: did you add margin_top=56 to your fragment_main layout.? May be it is overlapping with the toolbar